# Have a question of the React with map method

Tags: reactjs

I'm studying React now.
I have a question about the map method.
Is there any differences between productName1 and productName2? (except li part)

```
const productName1 = arr.map(a =><li>{a.name}</li> );
const productName2 = arr.map(a =>a.name );
```

Thank you.

```
    const arr = Data;
    
    // console.log(arr);
    
    const productName1 = arr.map(a =><li>{a.name}</li> );
    const productName2 = arr.map(a =>a.name );

    console.log(productImage);

    return (
        <div className="contents">   
        <h1>Please Select Products</h1>      
            <h3>{productName1}</h3>
            <h3>{productName2}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductData
```

Comment: How do you expect them to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are different, assuming your array is something like this:

```
const arr = [
  {name: "John"},
  {name: "Jane"},
  {name: "Jim"}
]
```

The generating html in the productName1 is something like this:

```
<h3>
 <li>John</li>
 <li>Jane</li>
 <li>Jim</li>
</h3>
```

Which in react is the equivalent of an array of JSX.Element's which is typed like this **JSX.Element[]**

While the result of productName2 will be this:

```
<h3>JohnJaneJim</h3>
```

Which is only a string array which will be typed like this string[]

So basically in the productName1 you're creating elements of li tags that contain the name which is creating invalid html since you need to wrap the li items inside and ol tag or an ul tag. The productName2 only generates an array of strings that will be mapped inside the h3

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So Is there no difference between them except li part you mean? Because I have no idea about arr.map(a =>a.name ) and arr.map(a =>{a.name}). In my eyes, it seems to be like props with {} Thank you!

Comment: No there's a big difference, one returns an array of JSX.Element's and the other an array of strings. arr.map(a =>{a.name}) this will return an undefined array because is an arrow function that does not have a return statement, this arr.map(a =>a.name ) does return a string array because is the shorthand of the arrow so it has a return statement. @Devon